# ERROR :- passing argument 1 of 'get_string' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, string, char, cs50

guys please tell what's wrong with my code.
I have added the cs50 library and the header file but can't seem to do it correct.
I am a begginer and like to know your advice.

**CODE :-**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.c>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Input:   ");
    printf("Output: ");
    int n = strlen(s);
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**ERROR :-**

```
3.c: In function 'main':
3.c:7:27: warning: passing argument 1 of 'get_string' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    7 |     string s = get_string("Input:   ");
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                           |
      |                           char *
In file included from 3.c:2:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/cs50.c:78:28: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char *'        
   78 | string get_string(va_list *args, const char *format, ...)
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
3.c:7:16: error: too few arguments to function 'get_string'
    7 |     string s = get_string("Input:   ");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from 3.c:2:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/cs50.c:78:8: note: declared here
   78 | string get_string(va_list *args, const char *format, ...)
```

Comment: Are you using a C or C++ compiler? Btw, you should include `cs50.h`, not `cs50.c`, if that library is like most others.

Comment: i'm running a C compiler and **cs50.c** works rather than  **cs50.c** on VS Code when i tried running both.

Comment: You should never (extremely rarely) include `.c` files. You should include the header file like the [documentation](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_string) says. Also, what @kaylum says below. (I can't upvote comments more today unfortunately)

Comment: "*cs50.c works rather than cs50.c*". Typo? That sentence doesn't make sense as "cs50.c" is repeated so please review it. It's not clear whether you understand and agree that the header not the C file should be included or whether you are still arguing against it.

Comment: when i use cs50.h,  they show this ERROR:-

C:\Users\RAJIBT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccB3dhet.o:3.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But not when i use cs50.c

Comment: That's actually one step closer to working than what you've got now. That means that you've missed to link with the cs50 library

Comment: I dont intend to argue i am just a begginer and don't know what to do, I'm sorry if you think i'm being rude

Comment: @MokshBansal No no, no problem. Just include `cs50.h` instead and add `-lcs50` to the end of the compilation command. `gcc -o executable source.c -lcs50`. If the `cs50` library is not installed in a standard search location, you need to provide that location too: `gcc -o executable source.c -Lpath_to_libcs50 -lcs50`

Comment: By "argue" I didn't mean you were being rude but just wanted you to clarify whether you accepted that C files should not be included (the fact that it fails in a different way shows you that that including the C file can't be "the" solution). Instead see this: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/38414/how-can-i-get-the-cs50-h-to-run-in-visual-studio-code. It explains how you need to build and link in the cs50 library and use it in VS Code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It shows the same result, I've tried 2 different methods

1. Built-in compiler

cd "c:\Users\rajib taid\Desktop\Moksh\language\c\" ; if ($?) { gcc 3.c -o 3 } ; if ($?) { .\3 }
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\RAJIBT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccU6VNWz.o:3.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

2. Manually compile

Show's the same result

Comment: @MokshBansal If you got that error message it means that you did not add `-lcs50` last on the line when  compiling. If it wasn't able to find the `cs50` library you would have gotten a different error. If the library is found, it would most likely link fine. Can you write the compilation command manually, on the command line like I showed it? Use the same `mingw` compiler as you use in your IDE. I just wrote `gcc` for short. It may have a longer name for you.

Comment: @kaylum
Ok, I too did had the question that don't you need to add the .h file instead of .c file, but the .c file seemed to work just fine, and i saw the video   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25b4LgOFyE
and did and thought that it may be correct

Comment: @MokshBansal Ok, if you followed that video, you may not have a library. You can then just add `cs50.c` to the compilation line: `gcc -o executable source.c cs50.c`

Comment: @TedLyngmo
It's gcc only and i just joined -lcs50 in between:- (The name of the file is 3.c)
gcc 3.c -lcs50 -o 3

It's ohk now first i'll join the cs50.h file properly, that might be the problem

Comment: "*the .c file seemed to work just fine*". Why do you keep saying that? It clearly didn't work "just fine" otherwise you wouldn't be here. It is almost never correct to include C files. Please follow the advice here. The simplest thing to do is to include the header file and then compile with `gcc -o 3 3.c cs50.c`.

Comment: @MokshBansal What happens if you do `gcc -c -o cs50.o cs50.c`? If that works, then do: `gcc -o executable source.c cs50.o` That way you don't have to recompile `cs50.c` every time. You can just reuse the object file.

Comment: i added the header file and recompiled but failed
**gcc -o 3 3.c cs50.c**
cc1.exe: fatal error: cs50.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

i'll add the header file again.

Comment: Well, where is the `cs50.c` file? If it is not in the current directory then give the path to it. Like: `gcc -o 3 3.c path_to_cs50/cs50.c`. I think perhaps you should review some tutorials on compiling and linking before proceeding further.

Comment: I just added a note to the Youtube video. I got really annoyed when I watched that video.

Comment: Yeah thanks for advice i'll just watch how to link and everything
Thanks for giving advice

Comment: @MokshBansal You're welcome! Btw, in the video, they placed the `cs50.c` file in the folder where the standard header files are. Did you do that too? If so, I recommend moving  the file from there. As a start, put it in the same folder as your `3.c` file and retry `gcc -o 3 3.c cs50.c`. You can later build a proper library of it and install that where _libraries_ are (not headers) and life will be better :-)

Comment: Guys, I agree what including cs50.c is a terrible idea, but can this really cause the error message we see?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I couldn't see any recent comment on that video. Did it get deleted? I've put some message there. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't know what happens when `cs50.c` is included but when Mokush included `cs50.h` instead, it compiled. It's only the linking left to figure out. My comment seems to still be there. Added 37 minutes ago.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, you should accept it. That makes this question also available as target for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It was already stated in comments and the previous answer that you should not include the `cs50.c` file but only include the `cs50.h` file and link the `cs50.c` file to your project.

That is generally true unless you have very specific reasons to do it differently.

But... normally this should not cause the error we see in the question.
This is because the `cs50.c` file included `cs50.h` on its own and we should have all definitions and declaration visible.

In this specific case we hit some specific implementation detail of CS50 libary which comes a bit as a surprise. And would not be necessary also...

Let's take a closer look at the header:

```c
// cs50.h
string get_string(va_list *args, const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)));
#define get_string(...) get_string(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)
```

After these 2 lines we can use `get_string` as intented by the author of this question: `string s = get_string("Input:   ");`

It is not really obvious why anyone might think it is a good idea to hide a function behind a macro with same name but different parameters.
In most other APIs that function would have a different name than the macro.
But, nevermind...

Now let's look at the C file:

```c
// cs50.c
#include "cs50.h"
...
#undef get_string
string get_string(va_list *args, const char *format, ...)
{
...
}
```

If you compile this file on its own, everything is fine. The `.c` file does not need the macro and can just get rid of it before defining the function.

But if you include this in your own file, where you are supposed to use the macro instead, this is not possible any more.
The `undef` breaks the API if you include the file directly.

This emphasises the fact that you should only include the headers. They are meant to be included and they are made accordingly. The `.c` files holding the implementation are not necessarily made that way, as we can see...

As a side note: This `#undef` is not necessary at all. You could simply do this instead:

```c
// cs50.c
#include "cs50.h"
...
string (get_string)(va_list *args, const char *format, ...)
{
...
}
```

With enclosing `()` the indentifier `get_string` does not match the macro `get_string()` any more and no replacement is done.
This would even allow to include the `.c` file directly.

Maybe they chose that way intentionally to prevent including the c file, but I would not bet on that.

Answer (score 0):

The cs50 docs states you should be including `cs50.h`, not `cs50.c`.
https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/#c.get_char
https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/#c.get_string

You need to add the header file in your include path.